# What is the significance of the grandmother's missing finger?

Tags: the-witches

In the 1990 movie "The Witches" the camera shows the Grandmother missing the end of a pinky finger on one of her hands. It's hinted that it was from a possible confrontation with the head witch during the grandmother's child-hood, but it's never expressly explained. Is there a full explanation of what happened to the grandmother and how or why she lost her finger?

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I can tell. From the book, there is only this discussion. Likely changed for the movie since a shortened pinky finger was an easier special effect than a missing thumb.

> "Grandmamma," I said, "when you were a little girl, did you ever meet
>   a witch?"
>
> "Once," my grandmother said. "Only once."
>
> "What happened?"
>
> "I'm not going to tell you," she said. "It would frighten you out of
>   your skin and give you bad dreams."
>
> "Please tell me," I begged.
>
> "No," she said. "Certain things are too horrible to talk about."
>
> "Does it have something to do with your missing thumb?" I asked.
>
> Suddenly, her old wrinkled lips shut tight as a pair of tongs and the
>   hand that held the cigar (which had no thumb on it.) began to quiver
>   very slightly.
>
> I waited. She didn't look at me. She didn't speak. All of a sudden she
>   had shut herself off completely. The conversation was finished.
>
> "Goodnight, Grandmamma," I said, rising from the floor and kissing her
>   on the cheek.
>
> She didn't move. I crept out of the room and went to my bedroom.